# Magento2 WebshopApps Matrix rate extension issue with additional discount label in cart page

Tags: magento2, shipping, shopping-cart, totals, gift-card

I have installed WebshopApps Matrix rate extension for my website in M2, i have also one custom module that shows gift card discount in cart page totals section,issue is when ajax call response comes from WebshopApps Matrix rate extension, my custom module gift card discount label disappears. when I disable WebshopApps Matrix rate extension it works fine. can anyone faced this type of issue and help me? please find 2 screenshots, one is for before shipping ajax call and one is after shipping ajax call.
[image: before shipping ajax call]
[image: after shipping ajax call]

Thanks,
Bhargav